# Set a variable in iReport/Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report using many variables to calculate a rolling inventory over 16 months.  The users are requesting some difficult calculations in the rollover amount (or carryover) such as only carryover amounts > 0, but only for some categories(groups), and then add the carryover from one category to the carryover in another category.  I have most of the issues worked out, but I need to set a variable for the carryover ONLY when the group =`"XXX"`, and maintain that variable value even when the group changes.  I can easily set the variable to change over categories (groups) `$F{group1}=="XXX"?QTY_ON_HAND - QTY_ORDERED:0.0`, but  when the group changes to `"YYY"` and then to `"ZZZ"` the value of the variable changes to 0.  I need to use the value of the variable when it is in the `"XXX"` group as part of the calculation when it gets to group `"ZZZ"`, but if it resets to 0 at that time, it is useless.  I have also tried setting the variable = `$V{rollover_amount}` and have tried that changing the Calculation Type, Reset Type, and Increment Types to no avail.

I have the Calculation set to "No Calculation", Increment and Reset types set to "None"

I am using *Jaspersoft Studio 5.5*, but the same would apply to *iReport* Designer.

Comment: I am assuming group XXX is something like non-fat milk, and YYYY is something like milk, and ZZZZ is something like beverages? Do you have a table that maps out this hierarchical relationship?

Answer (score 0):

I see two potential approaches. 
1) It looks like you've already started by creating the calculation by using conditional logic in the Variable Expression property. Continue with this approach. Try resetting the variable to itself when the group condition fails. Something like:
$F{group1} == "XXX" ? {do what you need to do} : $F{group1}

2) Use a JasperReport Scriptlet and manage the logic outside the report.
http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/scriptlet/